# The use of dt in brownian motion simulations.

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-approximation

Let's say that I have daily data over three years of some stochastic process. 
I use Maximum likelihood method to estimate the process. 
Let's Say its a Ornstein Uhlenbeck Process, now I have often wondered why if i have daily data the increment dt becomes 1/365
$$dx(t)=\sigma  dw(t)+\theta  dt (\mu -x(t))$$

Now if I have data in daily intervals and I use MLE to find the parameters of this process, or regression I have always wondered why I see examples using dt to become 1/365. 
I if we have  Wiener Process with following conditions I can agree that standard deviation is the square root of the variance.

[image]

Now from this I believe that:

$$\sqrt{\sigma ^2 t}=\sigma  \sqrt{t}$$

Now I have often seen that : 
$$\sigma   dw(t)$$

being written as

$$\sigma *\sqrt{\text{dt}}*\text{random}(\text{mean}=0,\text{variance}=1)$$

when simulating.

But regardless of if I am simulating a year or 3 years they always use dt=1/365 but I just dont understand why just because I have daily I need to divide by 365. In other words since I am estimating the parameters over a three year period and I have a daily time period, and I am going to use the parameters to simulate daily prices where is the requirement to divide by 365 coming from.

Of course I understand that 365 is number of days in a year, I just dont see the connection since I am estimating the parameters over daily data in a 3 year period why I would need to define dt as 1/365.

I would expect the yearly volatility to be $\sigma  \sqrt{365}$ if  $\sigma$ was daily volatility.

I would really appreciate any help I could get including a explanation or pointers to where I have gone wrong in terms of what I have written.

I have spent a long time trying to understand this and I would really appreciate any help I could get. I am very happy to edit the question if it would make it more understandable.

Comment: What units of time do you use?

Comment: Day, the data i am estimating is in a daily time series.

Comment: If you set dt to 1/356 this implies that your unit will be years. It does not matter in the end as long as you make all units consistent. In particular the units of $\theta$ are inverse time units and the units of $\sigma$ are whatever units your process has times the square root of time. Sometimes the measurement interval is much larger than the dt required to simulate the process (as that depends on the parameters that are not known in advance), in which case you must use special techniques. This question, with more details on the problem you are trying to solve, would fit on stats.se.

Comment: The MLE for $\theta$ and $\mu$ should have an analytical solution for known $\sigma$ (if observations are continuous).